# how to embed perl script in c program?

Tags: perl

Actually I've got an idea but to do that I need your help.Tell me is there any way to create a library in perl script ? I mean what is the command to create a library in perl ?and how can i include that library in my c program and run it ? I read somewhere that you can embedd your perl script in your c program but how can I make it?I want to create a special library on strings using perl script and use it in my c program.Help me guys.Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to run the Perl script with your input and grab the output.

Comment: funny it doesnt make any sense

Comment: Embedding Perl in C is possible, but only if you read Perl's documentation: perlembed.  Even then, it's hardly trivial.  Maybe if you could tell us what task you're trying to accomplish (not how you want to accomplish it, but what you actually want to do) we might help you to find a solution that is more within the reach of mortals.

Answer (score 6):

To actually include a perl interpreter in your C program and be able to execute perl code, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html.  Since perl is an interpreted language, there isn't a mandatory step of creating a library from your perl code.

But again, you really need to do some basic reading to learn at least the rudiments of the language first.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Perl allows you to reuse code by creating modules:

**`Foo.pm`**

```
package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub bar {
    print "foobar";
}

1;
```

Later, you could reuse the code in a script like:

**`foobar.pl`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Foo;

Foo::bar;
```

Quoting yourself ([*cody*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/820867/cody)):

> Guys perl is not as easy i thought its
>   so confusing thing.

To learn Perl, try following a book like Learning Perl, or tutorials on the internet like [Perl Beginners' Site](http://perl-begin.org/) or [Learn Perl](http://learn.perl.org/).

Comment: hey wait a minute what these foo::bar mean ?

Comment: That is the syntax for calling the function `bar` within the package `foo`.

Comment: how to include a library path in perl

Comment: but how to call a perl function from c and pass the variables back

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Any way, please read: `perldoc -q lib`.

Comment: I am not sure about that. Please check the other answers.

Comment: I mean i want to pass a string that is written in c program and pas sit to a perl program for some calculation and then send it back to the c program how can i do that>?

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, the best way to do it is by a system call:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  int RetVal, Arg1, Arg2;
  RetVal=system ("perl Script.pl Arg1 Arg2");
  return 0;
}
```

If you also need to analyze the script's output, you can redirect it to a file and read the file in C.

Comment: ok it runs the perl script but if i want to pass c variables to perl program do some stuff and get back them like you pass your variables to functions in the similar way and other thing what does retval contains?0 or 1?

Comment: how to include a library path in perl

Comment: and why your sending arg1 and arg2 ?